# Good MVC design with multiple repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have started to doubt my initial design decision, as everywhere I look I find tutorials on MVC where they just dump the access layer right into the MVC project. (Which goes against everything I've learned)

[image: UML Diagram of my design]

- **BarRepo**: Handles access to an API.
- **FooRepo**: Handles access to my Database (using EF).
- **FooBarHandler**: Joins data from the two repos into useful data for the controller.
- **Controller**: A controller, nothing speical.

As you can see in the picture, I've split up each part into their own project and try to obtain loose coupling. So I don't send Entity Framework classes out of the database layer and so on. However I've run into a bit of a pickle. The data amount fetched have become so large that it's noticeable on the frontend, so I needed to introduce paging. So I followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
My "problem" is that now MVC, Logic and the Database projects are depended on PagedList, so things aren't so neat and shiny anymore.

So my question is what would you have done?

Comment: For the most part, it sounds like you did the right thing.  A suggestion I have would be to use Stored Procedures to help speed things up on your DB interaction.  They're not as fun to work with as EF but they do a better job with massive volumes of data and trimming down said data to minimal amounts also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use PagedList as you can create a paged list of items yourself. Take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184/how-do-i-use-linq-for-paging-a-generic-collection) for an example of how to do this.

To summarise:

```
var pageNum = 3;
var pageSize = 20;

var pagedItems = data.Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

That way you will have no dependancies on PagedList, which will help reduce the coupling in your design.

Comment: This seems like a legit solution :)